# Tikz line along path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would need support for Tikz trick so that it become possible to self define the drawing along a path.

Below is the code I use:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{standalone}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}
\draw[  %
        black,  %
        line cap = round, 
        line width = 7pt
        ]   %
                (+00.00,-04.35) to [curve through={ %
                                                    (+01.25,-02.90) ..  % B
                                                    (+00.00,-01.45) ..  % C
                                                    (-01.25,+00.00) ..  % D
                                                    (+00.00,+01.45) ..  % E
                                                    (+01.25,+02.90) ..  % F
                                                    (+00.00,+04.35) ..  % G
                                                    (-01.25,+02.90) ..  % H
                                                    (+00.00,+01.45) ..  % I
                                                    (+01.25,+00.00) ..  % J
                                                    (+00.00,-01.45) ..  % K
                                                    (-01.25,-02.90)     % L
                                                    }
                ]
                (+00.00,-04.35);
\end{scope}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}
\path[  %
        postaction={    %
                     decorate,
                     decoration={   %
                                text along path,
                                reverse path=true,
                                raise=-0.1cm,
                                text color = white,
                                text={
                                      !! MISSING TEXT !!
                                    }
                                }   %
                    }
        ]   %
                (+00.00,-04.35) to [curve through={ %
                                                    (+01.25,-02.90) ..  % B
                                                    (+00.00,-01.45) ..  % C
                                                    (-01.25,+00.00) ..  % D
                                                    (+00.00,+01.45) ..  % E
                                                    (+01.25,+02.90) ..  % F
                                                    (+00.00,+04.35) ..  % G
                                                    (-01.25,+02.90) ..  % H
                                                    (+00.00,+01.45) ..  % I
                                                    (+01.25,+00.00) ..  % J
                                                    (+00.00,-01.45) ..  % K
                                                    (-01.25,-02.90)     % L
                                                    }
                ]
                (+00.00,-04.35);
\end{scope}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Without the second scope, the output looks like that:

[image]

but I would like to obtain something like that:

[image]

The idea is:

1. To keep the Tikz code as easy as possible, ideally with coordinates to keep "hobby" library  functionalities: final drawn is different and I don't want to calculate all coordinates by myself
2. Get the possibility to define the line "type" with something  like text = {--- . . -- . .}, giving short lines, dots and long lines as I want and the starting point on the path
3. Have the possibility to define white shadow when different lines are crossing
4. Keep the possibility to define the line width (here 7pt)
5. Keep the round cap.

I tried with the text decoration but no chance to make it work... Any idea how to solve this ? By using other packages ? Define new commands ?

Thank you for support !

Comment: PS: The use of text decoration is of course only for illustration purpose as the use of "---" would lead to straight lines, not following the given path, and leading to non smoothed output...

Comment: I am quite surprising that there is not TikZ solution so far. At least, that can be done with Asymptote (better handling with path operations)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to *Black Mild*, I restarted the reading of the tik-pgf library's documentation where I indeed found the answer via the use of the "dash-pattern" option.

Below the resulting code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{standalone}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\xscale{2.00}
\def\yscale{5.00}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[dash pattern=on 13pt off 13pt on 45pt off 13pt on 20pt off 13pt]
\draw[  %
        blue!40,  %
        line cap = round, 
        line width = 7pt
        ]   %
                (+00.00,-04.35) to [curve through={ %
                                                    (+01.25,-02.90) ..  % B
                                                    (+00.00,-01.45) ..  % C
                                                    (-01.25,+00.00) ..  % D
                                                    (+00.00,+01.45) ..  % E
                                                    (+01.25,+02.90) ..  % F
                                                    (+00.00,+04.35) ..  % G
                                                    (-01.25,+02.90) ..  % H
                                                    (+00.00,+01.45) ..  % I
                                                    (+01.25,+00.00) ..  % J
                                                    (+00.00,-01.45) ..  % K
                                                    (-01.25,-02.90)     % L
                                                    }
                ]
                (+00.00,-04.35);
\end{scope}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

I will anyway follow the given advice and start Asymptote as it seems to offer a lot of advantages.

Thanks,

user240879